# Display ID on List view android xamarin (Auto Increment ID)

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I'm Having a problem on displaying my ID on the list view.

HERE is my name.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Lang;
using SQLite;
namespace CRUD
{
    public class name
    {
        [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string fullName { get; set;}

        public static explicit operator name(Java.Lang.Object v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

HERE is my ListViewAdapter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Lang;

namespace CRUD
{
    public class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {

        public TextView txtFName { get; set; }
        public TextView intID { get; set; }
    }
    public class ListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
        private Activity activity;
        private List<name> firstList;

        public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity, List<name> firstList)
        {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.firstList = firstList;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return firstList.Count;
            }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return firstList[position].Id;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var view = convertView ?? activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.listLayout, parent, false);

            var Fname = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.fullName);
            var Id = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ID);

            Fname.Text = firstList[position].fullName;
            Id.int = firstList[position].Id;
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see. i use int because its a number and it will auto increment. But the problem is in my adapter. int data type is not accepted This part:(Id.int = firstList[position].Id;). How to call int data type. Or is there any other solution to display the ID?

Comment: Ok, I'll try searching about SimpleCursorAdapter, What i want to achieve is when i click items inside listview. There will be a toast that will say what is the ID of the Item that i clicked. The Auto increment is only natural for ID right? correct me if I'm wrong. And Thanks for answering my question

Comment: can you give some examples sir? using my code above. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Its clear now. What i want now is to display the ID whenever i click an Item on the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `int` with `Text` and call `ToString()` on the `Id` property:

```
Id.Text = firstList[position].Id.ToString();
```

The `Id` is a `TextView` and it does not have a `int` property. The `Text` is what is displayed, but it is a string, so you cannot assign a number to it directly. Instead you have to convert it to `string`, which is possible with the `ToString()` method.

Comment: Will the Auto Increment still function if i change my ID to string?

Comment: The `AutoIncrement` attribute has nothing to do with display, it is a `EntityFramework`-based attribute which tells the database how to generate ID values. If you don't use a DB, then this is not the right approach and you would have to assign the value yourself during object construction for example.

Comment: I'm using SQLite as my Database, my goal is when i click an item on a listview, the ID of that Item will be called as Toast.

Comment: Hi,@enshinohara, you don't need change your ID to string if you are using SQLite. And I know the ID is the `PrimaryKey`, you just need to change your ID to string when you display it on your ListView, like @Martin has suggested.

Comment: @MartinZikmund, I get it now thank you very much your a life saver. I'm sorry, im just new to this stuff. Thank you also Joe :)

Comment: Glad to help :-) . If that solved your question, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey checkmark. Happy coding!

Comment: I have one more question. How to to make my ID auto increment. I think my codes up there is wrong. Can you help me with this too? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think you should mark this question as resolved and post a new one with this new problem. You can post a link here in the comments when you post the question :-) .